# How can I add different menu items to multiple context menus?

Tags: java, android

I need to change icon for my item menu when i click. (android)

Answer (score 0):

a basic example, when you create your menu

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

inside your res/menu folder you will change your icon inside your menu.xml file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/noticias" 
android:orderInCategory="0" android:title="Menu Item" android:icon="@drawable/menu_icon"></item>
</menu>
```

menu_icon.png must be inside res/drawable folder...